# Xcode, It can't drag the view above or below to some view in Interface builder

Tags: storyboard, xcode10

Xcode, It can't drag the view above or below to some view in Interfacebuilder (Xcode 9 and Xcode 10)

How to fix this bug? I can't find the article or resolution about this bug.

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3W1VTvEcINc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double click element in interface builder. Then go to editor->Arrange->Send to front/back